# Does Doxygen have support for branching or for C/C++ preprocessor

Tags: c++, c, doxygen

This might sound like a sci-fi feature request but I wonder if Doxygen has any of the two following features:

1. Generating the call/caller graphs after preprocessor ran over the input file.
   Example:

   ```
   #define MULTITHREADING 1
   ```

   and then blocks of code are enabled or disabled depending on whether `MULTITHREADING`  is enabled.
2. Describing the *certainty of the call* with graph arrows... for example a dotted line if the function isn't always called (a.k.a it is in a branch or you have possible `return` before the function is called.

Answer (score 5):

For the first item, you will want to enable the [`ENABLE_PREPROCESSING`](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/config.html#cfg_enable_preprocessing) option in your `Doxyfile`.

For the second, I honestly don't know, but would be very surprised if it did. I think that this would require a full C/C++ compiler to determine these things.

Comment: are you sure ENABLE_PREPROCESSING works as I expect it to work. From what I can see call graph is generated even for code that is never generated with current defines

Comment: To be honest, I'm not sure the Doxygen parser is up to this task. Perhaps you have more luck asking on the [mailing list](https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/doxygen-users).

Comment: tnx... one day theyll switch to clang for parsing. :D

Comment: I sure hope they do. In the mean-time you can take a look at [cldoc](https://github.com/jessevdk/cldoc), a project in it's very early stages, or directly use the new [comment AST introspection API](http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/group__CINDEX__COMMENT.html) to roll your own :-P

Answer (score 5):

1. Doxygen [Preprocessing](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/preprocessing.html):

   > Source files that are used as input to doxygen can be parsed by
   >   doxygen's built-in C-preprocessor.
   >
   > By default doxygen does only partial preprocessing. That is, it
   >   evaluates conditional compilation statements (like #if) and evaluates
   >   macro definitions, but it does not perform macro expansion.
2. [COLLABORATION_GRAPH](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/config.html#cfg_collaboration_graph):

   > If the COLLABORATION_GRAPH and HAVE_DOT tags are set to YES then
   >   doxygen will generate a graph for each documented class showing the
   >   direct and indirect implementation dependencies (inheritance,
   >   containment, and class references variables) of the class with other
   >   documented classes.

Comment: for me PP didnt work, im not talking about macro exp... i even checked g++ PP output to file and checked it... it could be I was doing smthing wrong... would be nice if ppl could confirm/deny this one way or another...